# Create a column with periodically repeated values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data frame df with one column:

```
     Cost 
      30
      49
      98
      10
      37
      20
      10
      48
      70
      20
      30
      40
      50
      29
      90
      39
      30
      29
      50
      40
```

and a list: `id_list = ["A","B","C","D"]`  which is a list with 4 different id types. I would like to create a new column in the data frame where the first 5 cost values will be "A" the next 5 cost values will be "B" .... and the last 5 cost values will be "D". Therefore,  I want to repeat the elements of the id_list   5 times and my new df will be like this:

```
     Cost    ID

      30     A
      49     A
      98     A
      10     A
      37     A
      20     B
      10     B
      48     B
      70     B
      20     B
      30     C
      40     C
      50     C
      29     C
      90     C
      39     D
      30     D
      29     D
      50     D
      40     D
```

My actual data frame has many rows and the actual id_list has many elements.
The row-number is multiple of 5 so there will be an exact fill in the final data frame. 
In general I know how to add a column with specific values in pandas data frame
but I don't know how to do this with the repeated values.
Could you suggest how can I do this in python?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is function from `numpy` , `repeat`

```
df['New']=np.repeat(id_list,5)
df
Out[23]: 
    Cost New
0     30   A
1     49   A
2     98   A
3     10   A
4     37   A
5     20   B
6     10   B
7     48   B
8     70   B
9     20   B
10    30   C
11    40   C
12    50   C
13    29   C
14    90   C
15    39   D
16    30   D
17    29   D
18    50   D
19    40   D
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Numpy free v1

```
df.assign(ID=sum(zip(*[id_list] * 5), tuple()))

    Cost ID
0     30  A
1     49  A
2     98  A
3     10  A
4     37  A
5     20  B
6     10  B
7     48  B
8     70  B
9     20  B
10    30  C
11    40  C
12    50  C
13    29  C
14    90  C
15    39  D
16    30  D
17    29  D
18    50  D
19    40  D
```

---

### Numpy free v2

```
df.assign(ID=[x for x in id_list for _ in range(5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this, which takes advantage of the `[item]*n => [item, item, item, ...]` expansion that python does:

```
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
num = 5

repeated = []
for i in labels:
    repeated.extend([i]*num)
```

You can then add the column to your dataframe.